# Struggling to understand definition of "matrix of endomorphism $f$ in basis $a$" - what does it really mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having an exam from linear algebra in a few days and I'm trying to understand some definitions from my workbook. Here's a definition I can't wrap my head around:

Let's assume we have two bases in vector space $X$:  **a**$=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and **b**$=(b_1,...,b_n)$. Let $f$ be an endomorphism of vector space $X$ (this is defined earlier as linear transformation from $X$ to $X$) and let $M_{f,a}\in\Bbb{R}^{n,n}$ be a matrix of endomorphism $f$ in basis **a**. That means that for:

$x=\alpha_1 a_1+...+\alpha_n a_n$; $\alpha=[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]^T$

we have:

$f(x)=\theta_1 x_1+...+\theta_n x_n$, for $[\theta_1,..\theta_n]^T=\theta=M_{f,a}\alpha$

So - what could author of these words have in mind? I cannot find "matrix of endomorphism" on Google and I don't understand what are $x_1,...,x_n$ - in definition we suddenly have this basis(?) undefined earlier and $M_{f,a}$ is suddenly matrix of change of basis **a** to that "wild" basis. So, is there any easier and more straightforward way to understand this $M_{f,a}$?

Comment: A native English speaker might say instead: "let $M$ be **the** matrix of **the** endomorphism $f$ in **the** basis $\mathbf{a}$".

Comment: $x_i$ could be any specify basis in $X$ which we assign to $M_{f,a}$, in this case I think $x_i$ should be $a_i$, since it is the only symbol mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_{f,a}$ is the matrix that *corresponds* to (or *represents*) the endomorphism $f$ for the choice of basis $a$.

$x$ is any vector.  $\alpha$ corresponds to $x$, when you choose the basis $a$.

All this is doing is taking the abstract idea of an endomorphism--which is just a linear function from vectors to vectors--and writing it in a basis, so that you can *compute* this function's action on any input vector simply through matrix multiplication.

Comment: So what are vectors $x_1,...,x_n$? If I understand your answer correctly, if we take $M_{f,a}\alpha$ we should get coordinates of a "transformed" vector in basis **a** and in that "definition" we have some weird $\theta$ coordinates in basis $x_1,...,x_n$...

Answer (score 1):

Working through an illustrative example in a more concrete setting will help:
Take your vector space $X$ to be the collection of polynomials in a variable $t$  of degree less than or equal to, say 2. This is a vector space of dimension 3, with one obvious basis **a**=$\{1,t,t^2\}$. Can check easily that **b**=$\{t^2-1,t, t^2+1\}$is another basis for $X$.

Define $D$ (I am avoiding your $f$)
to be the differentiation with respect to $t$ which is clearly an endomorphism of $X$. Now write the matrix of $D$: consider for first column $\frac d{dt}(1)$, second column $\frac d{dt}(t)$ and third column $\frac d{dt}(t^2)$ all expressed with respect to the basis **b**.

First column is clearly the zero vector. The second column is $(\frac{-1}2, 0, \frac12)^T$, because $\frac d{dt}(t) = -\frac 12(t^2-1) + 0. t +\frac12(t^2+1)$. This way you can compute third column as $(0,2,0)^T.$

Hope this explains the meaning of matrix of a linear transformation with respect to given choices of bases.